# Cast one derrived class to another without changing base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

I have several child classes all having same parent. Each child class can be constructed using some data that is contained in parent object. I would like to cast one child to be another child using info contained in base object (without modifying base object).

Currently it is implemented as illustrated in following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data {};
class base
{
public:
    base()  {}
    base(Data input) : data(input)  {}
    virtual ~base() {   cout << "Deleting :" << this->name() << endl;   }
    template<class T> static base* CastToDerrived(base* object)
    {
        T* output = new T(object->data);
        delete object;
        return output;
    }
    virtual const char* name()  {return "base";}
    Data data;
};

class derrived1 : public base
{
public:
    derrived1() {}

    derrived1(Data input): base(input){}
    ~derrived1(){cout << "Deleting :" << this->name() << endl;}
    const char* name(){return "derrived1";}
};

class derrived2 : public base
{
public:
    derrived2(){}
    derrived2(Data input): base(input){}
    ~derrived2(){cout << "Deleting :\t" << this->name() << endl;}
    const char* name(){return "derrived2";}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    base* object = new derrived1();
    cout << "Created :\t"<<object->name()<<endl;
    object = base::CastToDerrived<derrived2>(object);
    cout << "Casted to :\t"<<object->name()<<endl;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Created :   derrived1
Deleting :derrived1
Deleting :base
Casted to : derrived2
```

However, this requires base class to be destroyed and created again, which I would like to avoid - I would like to destroy derrived1, use base to construct derrived2, but keep the base class intact. What is the best way to do that?

(There are several derived classes, base class provides common interface for all, some derived class will be added later without modifying the base).

Comment: So you want to *move* the base object?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would like to move it, however I need to destroy one child and create another using base object

Comment: Don't use inheritance but composition! You move a pointer to base class implementation around your classes and it won't ever be destroyed (because you keep a reference counter).

Comment: @Adriano, yes, that could work, but base class provided interface for all the children - by doing it through inheritance I can use pointer to base class for all children and their interface and add new children without modifying code that uses them, how would I do that with composition?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy, you could make the base class just hold a pointer to a structure containing all the "base" fields.  That'll let you transfer ownership of that structure from one object to another, without losing the benefits of polymorphism.

Comment: It depends what kind of relationship you have. The concept is pretty similar to the `Decorator` pattern (or `Proxy`, according to what exactly you're trying to describe the right pattern can be something else) applied with a `shared_ptr` used for reference counting of the contained object.

Comment: @Adriano, thanks, I've checked Decorator and Proxy patterns. There are several classes derived from same base, I would like to switch between them while keeping base intact. Decorator is overkill since all derived classes are mutually exclusive, Proxy can work but seems like adding complexity by introducing reference counting and shared pointer...

Comment: If you have to _switch_ between classes then Strategy pattern may be more appropriate but again the right one must be chosen carefully according to your domain. Shared pointers are the only option if you have to move ownership of one object to another one (unless deep copy can be applied then you don't need pointers at all). Yes, it adds some (little) complexity but most of the work is done by shared_ptr itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't destroy the derived class an keep the base class because it's the same instance.
we can demonstrate this using the folowing code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data {};
class base
{
public:
    base()
    {
        printf("base pointer = %08X\n", this);
    }
};

class derrived1 : public base
{
public:
    derrived1()
    {
        printf("derrived1 pointer = %08X\n", this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    base* object = new derrived1();
    delete object;
    return 0;
}
```

the output will show that base an derived1 is the same pointer
on the other hand you use some tricky code to achieve what you want.
the idea is to use a pointer to Data class instead of a variable.
your code will become then as folowing

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data {};
class base
{
public:
    base(){data = new Data}
    base(Data* input) : data(input)  {}
    virtual ~base() {   cout << "Deleting :" << this->name() << endl;   }
    template<class T> static base* CastToDerrived(base* object)
    {
        T* output = new T(object->data);
        delete object; 
        return output;
    }
    virtual const char* name()  {return "base";}
    Data* data;
};

class derrived1 : public base
{
public:
    derrived1() {}

    derrived1(Data* input): base(input){}
    ~derrived1(){cout << "Deleting :" << this->name() << endl;}
    const char* name(){return "derrived1";}
};

class derrived2 : public base
{
public:
    derrived2(){}
    derrived2(Data* input): base(input){}
    ~derrived2(){cout << "Deleting :\t" << this->name() << endl;}
    const char* name(){return "derrived2";}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    base* object = new derrived1();
    cout << "Created :\t"<<object->name()<<endl;
    object = base::CastToDerrived<derrived2>(object);
    cout << "Casted to :\t"<<object->name()<<endl;
}
```

i wish this will help.