# Call destructor of derrived class only

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, type-conversion

Looking at the C++ language standard, is there any way to call only derived class destructor, without calling destructor of the base class?

So, for classes

```
class Base { public: virtual ~Base() {} };
class Derived : public Base { public: ~Derived();};
```

if would be possible to write code like

```
Base *basePtr = new Derived();
//do something with basePtr

// Now somehow destroy Derived while keeping Base - call ~Derived() only, 
// line below however will call both ~Derived() and ~Base() - how it can be done?
dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePtr)->~Derived();
```

So, after execution of the code above basePtr will point to Base object only, like if it was created by

```
Base *basePtr = new Base();
```

plus any modifications to the Base object caused by manipulating basePtr between calling new Derived() and destroying Derived class?

Or, is this forbidden and it is impossible to do?

Comment: @NPE If this is possible, how can this be done???? The use case is motivated by question be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843549/cast-one-derrived-class-to-another-without-changing-base-class, I asked this part separately since now I'm curious if it is at all theoretically possible and how to do that...

Comment: Actually, I hadn't noticed the *while keeping `Base`* bit. I withdraw my previous comment.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have formulated the question, it is not possible to achieve what you are asking for. Unless you have a memory leak, the only case when explicitly calling a destructor does not lead to undefined behavior is if the object was created by placement new. Even then, calling the destructor will automatically call the destructor of every member and base class.

This is as it should be. Otherwise it would be very difficult to write a correct container class or memory manager.

The standard says that the lifetime of an object ends as soon as it enters the destructor. It does not become a base class object. It ceases to be an object, entirely. Also, if this was not the case, what would be the status of a class deriving from multiple bases after such a trick?

Ultimately, the "need" for such a functionality is a sign of bad design. I would guess your use case more likely requires composition. See if you can't solve it with a new class which holds one instance of what is currently the base class and one optional, replaceable component of (a smart pointer to) some dummy class which serves as an interface to and the new common base of your current derived classes. That way you can remove (and destruct) those sub objects without touching the base.

Comment: You can call the destructor explicitly without placement new, granted the destructor is never called, a.k.a. the memory is almost surely leaked.

Comment: @Griwes Good catch, I completely forgot about memory leaks. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The standard demands that the destruction of a Derived object destroys the whole object, including the Base subobject. Anything else would not be a destruction according to C++'s understanding of object lifetime.

Depending on what you want to achieve, consider to copy the Base out of the derived first

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> basePtr(new Derived());
//do something with basePtr

basePtr.swap(std::unique_ptr<Base> (new Base(*basePtr))); //splice the Base part out of the derived object

//basePtr now points to the spliced Base object.
```

Another approach would be to hold the additional members that derived has in a `boost::optional` (or just a pimpl) and reset that to get a "stripped" Derived object that still has its Base class part. This will however not affect virtual function dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are called automatically in the reverse order of construction. I do not believe there is any way around this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do unless your derived class has nothing to do with your base class.

Destructors are called in automatic way.Explicitly call destructor may result in undefined behavior.